# Does react-native supports Pintura Editor?

Tags: react-native

I want to use Pintura Editor in my **react-native** project, But it's not working and also didn't getting any error.
I am not able to understand where i am going wrong and does **react-native** supports **Pintura** ?

Is there any way i can solve this issue?

Any lead would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React-Native doesn't supports Pintura Editor yet. But we can use pintura with **WebView**, as Pintura is based on html technologies it will have to run in a WebView to work. Here is an example

```
Pintura_Editor.js
 
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import React, { forwardRef, useRef, useEffect,useState } from 'react';

const noop = () => {};
//For Making First letter uppercase.
const upperCaseFirstLetter = (str) => str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);
// PATH_TO_PINTURA.HTML file (need to download paid version)
const PinturaEditorProxy = require('./pintura.html');

const Editor = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
const { style, ...options } = props;
const webViewRef = useRef(null);
const [isStatus, setStatus] = useState(false)
    setInterval(()=> {
        setStatus(true)
    }, 3000)

// this passes options to the editor
useEffect(() => {
clearInterval();
    // setup proxy to call functions on editor
        const handler = {
            get: (target, prop) => {
                if (prop === 'history') return new Proxy({ group: 'history' }, handler);
                return (...args) => {
                    const name = [target.group, prop].filter(Boolean).join('.');
                    webViewRef.current.postMessage(
                        JSON.stringify({
                            fn: [name, ...args],
                        })
                    );
                };
            },
        };

        webViewRef.current.editor = new Proxy({}, handler);
        // post new options
        webViewRef.current.postMessage(JSON.stringify({ options: options }));
},[isStatus]);

return (
    <View ref={ref} style={style}>
        <WebView
            ref={webViewRef}
            javaScriptEnabled={true}
            scrollEnabled={false}
            domStorageEnabled={true}
            allowFileAccess={true}
            allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs={true}
            allowsLinkPreview={false}
            automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
            originWhitelist={['*']}
            textZoom={100}
            source={PinturaEditorProxy}
            onMessage={async (event) => {
                // message from WebView
                const { type, detail } = JSON.parse(event.nativeEvent.data);
               const handler =  await options[`on${upperCaseFirstLetter(type)}`] || noop;

                // call handler
                handler(detail);
            }}
        />
    </View>
);
});

export default Editor;
```

Now, import this editor to your **app.js**

```
 import PinturaEditor from 'PATH_TO_PINTURA_EDITOR'
 const editorRef = null;

 ....
 ....


render() {
return (
<PinturaEditor
      ref={editorRef}
      style={{ margin:40, width: '80%', height: '80%', borderWidth: 2, borderColor: '#eee' }}
      imageCropAspectRatio={1}
  // Image should be base64 or blob type 
      src={base64Image}
      onLoad={(img) => {
          // do something
      }}
      onProcess={async (image) => {
          // do something with edited image
        }}
/>)
}
```

Comment: How can i get pintura.html file

Comment: @ManojBhardwaj Pintura is paid, You need to purchase it.